# Python - run an async funtion after delay and do not block other code

Tags: python, asynchronous, timer, python-asyncio

Here is my code:

```
async def outer():
    # if this while loop was not broken in 5 seconds, do something
    while True:
        # some code with breaks
```

Generally i need a non-blocking asynchronous timer.

Comment: @python_user not, it blocks other code inside same funciton

Comment: Do you mean if `outer` is not completed in 5 seconds you need to do something?

Comment: @Ceres no, i need to check while's completion time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def outer():
    async def loop():
         #while loop here
  

    task = asyncio.create_task(loop())
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([task], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED, timeout=5)
    if task in done:
        # loop has completed
    else:
       # loop is incomplete
```

### References:

- [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives)