# Making a Discord bot disconnect from a voice channel after 10 minutes

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I’m trying to make my Discord bot (written in Python) disconnect after 10 minutes from a voice chat if the music queue is clear. I've no idea on how do it since I’ve started with Python like two weeks ago, and I’m  still trying to figure out things.

This is the bot structure:

```
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

    # All the music related stuff
    self.is_playing = False
    self.is_paused = False

    # Two-dimensional array containing [song, channel]
    self.music_queue = []
    self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
    self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
                           'options': '-vn'}

    self.vc = None
```

And this is the disconnect part. For now it only disconnects after a user type the command /leave:

```
@commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from VC")
async def dc(self, ctx):
    self.is_playing = False
    self.is_paused = False
    await self.vc.disconnect()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [run an async function after delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467369/python-run-an-async-funtion-after-delay-and-do-not-block-other-code)

Comment: You can store the timestamp when it leaves, and then have a task check that every few seconds or so and leave if the timestamp is far enough away.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you peek into the discord.py docs they have something called "tasks" which will allow you to schedule actions

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html